# How to solve this recurrence relation: T(n) = R(n-1) + n log n R(n) = T(n-1) + n^2

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, recurrence-relation, mathematical-analysis

How to solve this recurrence relation:

T(n) = R(n-1) + n log n

R(n) = T(n-1) + n^2

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you substituted one equation into the other.

Comment: The title is inconsistent with the body of the post.

Comment: $T(n)=T(n-2)+(n-1)^2+n\log(n)$. The solution will be $\sim\dfrac{n^3}6$.

Comment: ... because to calculate T(n) you just sum up (k-1)^2 + k log k for k = n-2, n-4, n-6 etc. Summing all squares is about n^3/3, summing only every second one is about n^3 / 6.

Answer (score 2):

How to solve:

- eliminate one of $T$ or $R$.
- write the homogeneous part of the recurrence and plug $T/R(n)=r^n$.
- after simplification, find the roots of the characteristic equation.
- express the solution as a linear combination of terms $r^n$.
- now you have to find particular solutions of the full equation.
- due to the particular values of the roots, you will see that they can be found by summation of the non-homogeneous parts. There are two terms.
- the first term can be summed using the Faulhaber formula.
- the second yields no easy analytical form and you need to fall back on an approximation.
- finally, plug the initial conditions and solve for the unknowns coefficients.
- from $T(n)$ you can easily draw $R(n)$ and conversely.

---

If you can satisfy yourself with a $\Theta$ representation, just perform steps 1 and 6.